Integrating acceleration + escape velocity over distance
I am not sure how to title this question so apologies if it's inaccurate.
If I throw an object at thrice the escape velocity of earth, what would be its velocity very far away from earth, (at a distance of infinity)?
I tried solving this question by noting that while the velocity (33.6 km/s) is constant, the acceleration is dependent on distance, I don't want to take acceleration as constant.
Acceleration is given by $\frac{GM}{(r+s)^2}$ where $s$ is the displacement of the object,
I thought I should integrate this distance dependent acceleration from $0$ to $\infty$ with respect to $s$ but then I get something which isnt a velocity or acceleration?
How do I solve this problem

I don't think there is a "ds" in the expression of acceleration.

Use conservation of energy i.e. KE + PE = constant

This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory

Your object can escape Earth, but it doesn't have enough orbital energy to escape the Sun.

With physics (and many other sciences as well), most of the time there are multiple approaches to solve a problem.
Of course, you can follow the path that the object describes, and integrate the varying acceleration as a function of distance, but that will be quite a complex maths task.
An easier approach uses conservation of energy: the sum of potential energy plus kinetic energy stays constant over all the path. As this question is labelled "homework-and-exercises", I won't solve the problem for you, but the following questions should bring you on track:

What is the potential energy of an object at earth's surface?
What is the potential energy of an object at infinity?
How much must the kinetic energy of the object change between surface and infinity to compensate for the change in potential energy?
What does that mean for its velocity?

Hint for relating velocity at surface level with potential energy: if an object starts with "escape velocity" from the surface, it will slow down to zero at infinity.
